# Binding in Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, bind

When I sync my collection, the server returns a JSON object which I want to add as new models to my collection. I've set it up like this:

```
syncCollection: function() {    
        Backbone.sync('create', this,  {
          success: function (msg) {
              console.log(this);
              this.add(msg, {at: 0});

          }
    }, this);
    }
```

The problem is that 'this' doesn't seem to point to the collection, instead it is defaulting to the global window object. I have attempted to bind `this` to the collection but it doesn't seem to work:

```
initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'syncCollection');
    },
```

How can I use .bind to ensure that `this` points to the collection and not the window object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var that = this` at the beginning of the outer function(i.e. just before `Backbone.sync`), and replace `this` with `that` in the inner function(i.e. `success`).

Note: In JavaScript `this` always refers to the **owner** of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

BTW, you don't have to use `_.bindAll`, `_.bind` is enough.